# Javascript sums total with addrow

Tags: javascript, php

First of all, sorry for my bad english language.

So, I want to sums my 2 coloumn, but i have add.row condition.
Here my code :

```js
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.qty, .unit').on('blur', function(e){
    var qty = parseFloat( $('.qty').val() ), 
        unit = parseFloat( $('.unit').val() );
    
    if( isNaN(qty) || isNaN(unit) ) {
      $('.result').text('');
      return false;
    }
    
    var total = qty * unit;
    $('.result').text( total );
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" name="p_qty[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control unit" name="p_harga[]" /></td>
<td><strong><span class="result" name="p_jumlah[]"></span></strong></td>
```

here my screenshoot
[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szRHL.png)

when im run, this code success but only in row 1 and not work in row 2++
how can i fix it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script src="../js/plugins/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.form-control').blur(function () {
            var qty = $('.qty').val();

            var total = 0;

            $('.unit').each(function () {
                total += parseInt(this.value);
            });

            // Update the total
            $('.result').text(qty * total);
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" class="form-control qty" name="p_qty[]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control unit" name="p_harga[]" />

<!-- Two or more fields -->
<input type="text" class="form-control unit" name="p_harga[]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control unit" name="p_harga[]" />

<strong><span class="result" name="p_jumlah[]"></span></strong>
```